# Huawei without Google Play: will I be forced to create a Huawei account?

Tags: huawei, privacy

I wish to buy a Huawei P30 Lite phone. It's a phone without the Google services and play. Can I use this phone without a Huawei account? Only use `F-Droid` apps?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play is available on Huawei P30 Lite.
http://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html

Only Huawei devices that are produced after the Google Ban, which is 20 May 2019 do not have Google Play Services.

You will not be forced to create a Huawei account in order to use the phone. Huawei account is only needed you are using specific apps on the Huawei devices.